# sun.text.Normalizer doesn't exist in JDK6

Tags: java, normalize

I use following APIs import sun.text.Normalizer with JDK5:

- public static String decompose(String str, boolean compat, int
  options)
- public static final int getClass(int ch)
- public static String normalize(String str, Mode mode, int options)

How do I upgrade code to JDK6 to achieve the same function?
I search by google, but no result. thank you so much for tips.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [java.text.Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html). It has the method `normalize`.

Comment: yep since JDK 1.6 `java.text.Normalizer` replaces `sun.text.Normalizer`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at
[API java.text.Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html)

As I'm comparing, sun.text.Normalizer and java.text.Normalizer, they seem quite the same.